# iOS VOIP app and phone restart

Tags: ios, voip, restart

I have a VOIP enabled app, that has suitable codes to enable the app to run on background. The app runs fine (say for example it is able to receive calls) when its on background.

Now, when I restart the phone (with my app in question running on the background), I see after the restart the app is there on the list of apps running (this I am able to verify by double tapping the home button). However, my app is not actually running on the background, it does not receive any calls.

Once I open the app, it 'relaunches' and is now able to receive calls. Is this the expected behaviour? Or am I missing something? I need to renewable the app in background mode once the phone is restarted.

Comment: When you double-tap the Home button, the list of apps that appear is NOT a list of running apps. It's a list of recently used apps. Some may be suspended in the background, some may not be. You have no way to know.

Comment: So, you have included "voip" in the background modes string?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I do have that.

Comment: I am running in the same problem, did you get any solution. Can you share with me? Thanks.